# Ruby split string block 2 levels error

Tags: ruby

I want to extract all the file names from text file

File temp.txt

```
Expand or Collapse
Add App To Favorites - Ajax;Plugin;AjaxOnSmallDevicesReveal_lmstat_1111.qvwDefault1899-12-30 05:30



Expand or Collapse
Add App To Favorites - Ajax;Plugin;AjaxOnSmallDevicesReveal_lmstat_140109_v2_reduced.qvwDefault2014-01-10 15:56



Expand or Collapse
Add App To Favorites - Ajax;Plugin;AjaxOnSmallDevicesReveal_lmstat_ONLYPV.qvwDefault2014-02-07 18:34
```

I am using the following code

```
file = File.open("temp.txt", "r")
   while (line = file.gets)     
       if line.text.include? "Devices"
           string=line.split("Devices")[1]
           File.open("out.txt", 'a') {|f| f.puts string.split(".qvw")[0] + ".qvw" }
           end
   end
file.close
```

But somehow I end up with the following error for the split function.

```
1) Error:
test_script(M_Dev_Script):
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
M_Test_Script.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in file2'
M_Test_Script.rb:65:in `open'
```

As per the error message I am able to make know that the error is at

> string.split(".qvw")[0]

But I am not able to find a proper solution to the error, please any help?

Comment: as the error message says, `string` is `nil`. do some tracing.

Comment: @Karoly The error message indicates the string is nil, but I have made sure using puts that the `line.split("Devices")[1]` does hold some string.

Comment: I trust the compiler / error message. Consequently, I don't trust what you said. You're wrong.

Comment: For debugging, try printing `string` straight after the line: `string=line.split("Devices")[1]`, and leave out `File.open...` line for now. This way you can first establish if the `string`'s values are what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the original code, I get an `undefined method 'text'` on your `line.text.include?` expression. `line` is already a string and you don't need to select out `text`.

Try this:

```
open("temp.txt", "r").each do |line|
  if line.include? "Devices"
    string=line.split("Devices")[1]
    open("out.txt", 'a') {|f| f.puts string.split(".qvw")[0] + ".qvw" }
  end
end
```

Or a little more simply:

```
open("out.txt", "a") do |f|
  open("temp.txt", "r").each do |line|
    f.puts line.split("Devices")[1].split(".qvw")[0] + ".qvw" if line.include? "Devices"
  end
end
```

Yields:

```
$ cat out.txt
Reveal_lmstat_1111.qvw
Reveal_lmstat_140109_v2_reduced.qvw
Reveal_lmstat_ONLYPV.qvw
```